# How to log sql queries when app startup

Tags: sql, grails, logging

How to log the sql queries ( insert, create ,alter ) in grails application when the app start for the first time. I tried with log_sql true but it logging only when application is running not when application starting?

Answer (score 0):

In your Datasource.groovy file add this to your hibernate closure:

```
hibernate{
    show_sql=true
}
```

All your queries, even those executed during bootstrap (startup), should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want this to happen in the development environment, add the following to `DataSource.groovy`

```
environments {

    development {
        dataSource {
            logSql = true
        }

        hibernate {
            format_sql = true
        }
    }
}
```